# Git n commit behind | n ahead

Tags: git, github, merge, gitlab, branch

I'm using gitlab and there is a project where a person have already pushed her work and merged it with master and i created a new branch and pushed it to remote and made a merge request but the issue is that it says my branch is 3 commit behind 2 ahead so it can't be merged. (The project i m trying to merge is actually the same that is in master. )I don't know how to resolve this. Shouldn't my branch start from HEAD on master and not be behind ? I'm new to git so i'm sorry if i'm being dumb.

Comment: I would *rebase* the PR branch onto the updated target branch. Another approach is to *merge* the remote (PR target) branch back into the PR branch, although usually dirties the history a bit - search for “git pr merge conflict” for no shortage of walkthroughs.

Comment: "Behind" is with reference to the tip of the remote master branch. 

Your local master branch is behind because someone else has pushed their work to master.


To resolve this, you can try pulling from master first, sorting out any merge conflicts, then pushing to master again.

Comment: Isnt there a way to just create a new branch based on master and merge it ?

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to handle this problem is by using **rebase**.
Git Merge and Git Rebase serve the same purpose. They are designed to integrate changes from multiple branches into one. Although the final goal is the same, those two methods achieve it in different ways.

**Git Merge**

Merging is a common practice for developers using version control systems. Whether branches are created for testing, bug fixes, or other reasons, merging commits changes to another location. To be more specific, merging takes the contents of a source branch and integrates them with a target branch. In this process, only the target branch is changed. The source branch history remains the same.
Pros

- Simple and familiar
- Preserves complete history and chronological order
- Maintains the context of the branch

Cons

- Commit history can become polluted by lots of merge commits
- Debugging using git bisect can become harder

**Git Rebase**

Rebase is another way to integrate changes from one branch to another. Rebase compresses all the changes into a single “patch.” Then it integrates the patch onto the target branch.

Unlike merging, rebasing flattens the history because it transfers the completed work from one branch to another. In the process, unwanted history is eliminated.

Pros

- Streamlines a potentially complex history
- Manipulating a single commit is easy (e.g. reverting them)
- Avoids merge commit “noise” in busy repos with busy branches

Cons

- Rebasing public repositories can be dangerous when working as a team
- It’s more work: Using rebase to keep your feature branch updated always
- Rebasing with remote branches requires you to force push.

Rebase the feature branch onto the master branch using the following commands.

```
$ git checkout feature
$ git rebase master
```

This moves the entire feature branch on top of the master branch. It does this by re-writing the project history by creating brand new commits for each commit in the original (feature) branch.

For more information, you could visit the git document
[https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/an-introduction-to-git-merge-and-rebase-what-they-are-and-how-to-use-them-131b863785f/#:~:text=Merging%20is%20a%20common%20practice,them%20with%20a%20target%20branch](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/an-introduction-to-git-merge-and-rebase-what-they-are-and-how-to-use-them-131b863785f)

Comment: at least give credit to the writer of the blog post you **copied** the content from. https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/an-introduction-to-git-merge-and-rebase-what-they-are-and-how-to-use-them-131b863785f/#:~:text=Merging%20is%20a%20common%20practice,them%20with%20a%20target%20branch.

Comment: You are right, Thanks for mentioning. I added the link